# Dynamic Depending Lists in VBA

Tags: vba, list, validation, excel, dynamic

I have found that code (on: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/) really useful:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, n As Long
Dim MyCol As Collection
Dim SearchString As String, TempList As String

Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error GoTo Whoa

'~~> Find LastRow in Col A
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
    Set MyCol = New Collection

    '~~> Get the data from Col A into a collection
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Len(Trim(Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            MyCol.Add CStr(Range("A" & i).Value), CStr(Range("A" & i).Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Create a list for the DV List
    For n = 1 To MyCol.Count
        TempList = TempList & "," & MyCol(n)
    Next

    TempList = Mid(TempList, 2)

    Range("D1").ClearContents: Range("D1").Validation.Delete

    '~~> Create the DV List
    If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
        With Range("D1").Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
'~~> Capturing change in cell D1
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then
    SearchString = Range("D1").Value

    TempList = FindRange(Range("A1:A" & LastRow), SearchString)

    Range("E1").ClearContents: Range("E1").Validation.Delete

    If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
        '~~> Create the DV List
        With Range("E1").Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
End If

LetsContinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

'~~> Function required to find the list from Col B
Function FindRange(FirstRange As Range, StrSearch As String) As String
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
Dim strTemp As String

Set aCell = FirstRange.Find(what:=StrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

ExitLoop = False

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = FirstRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop
    FindRange = Mid(strTemp, 2)
End If
End Function
```

That code works but when I try to put the DV list to another sheet and change the cells to write on, it doesn't work correctly...

When I select the option what I want to the list, the selected option is not written on the cell.

So the program runs without any problem but the result, it's not what i want.

The rearranged code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, n As Long
Dim MyCol As Collection
Dim SearchString As String, Templist As String

Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error GoTo Whoa

' Find LastRow in Col A
LastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
Set MyCol = New Collection

' Get the data from Col A into a collection
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Len(Trim(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MyCol.Add CStr(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value), CStr(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next i

' Create a list for the Data Validation List
For n = 1 To MyCol.Count
    Templist = Templist & "," & MyCol(n)
Next

Templist = Mid(Templist, 2)

Range("A2").ClearContents: Range("A2").Validation.Delete

' Create the Data Validation List
If Len(Trim(Templist)) <> 0 Then
    With Range("A2").Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Templist
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End If

' Capturing change in cell A2
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
SearchString = Range("A2").Value

Templist = FindRange(Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow), SearchString)

Range("B2").ClearContents: Range("B2").Validation.Delete

If Len(Trim(Templist)) <> 0 Then
    ' Create the DV List
    With Range("B2").Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Templist
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End If
End If
LetsContinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

' Function required to find the list from Col B
Function FindRange(FirstRange As Range, StrSearch As String) As String
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
Dim strTemp As String

Set aCell = FirstRange.Find(what:=StrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

ExitLoop = False

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = FirstRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop
    FindRange = Mid(strTemp, 2)
End If
End Function
```

Is there somebody who has any idea if I have to change something more? Is there something tricky that I'm missing?

Comment: meikse -> no one really wants to run through all the code to find out what is wrong. Since you know it doesn't work, you must have debugged it. If you can be more specific as to what is not working, we can help you better. I.e. - which line does it break on? What have you tried to resolve it?   Also, tell us what you are ultimately trying to do... there may be a much easier way, maybe without using VBA.

Comment: Sorry. I'm going to edit the post and explain it better.

Comment: Your main `If...ElseIf...End If` clauses are not mutually exclusive: the first checks for an intersection between the changed range and ColumnA: if this is true then your second one (intersect with A2) will also be true, but only the first one will run.

Comment: I could solve that adding "Sheet2" to Columns(1). But now appers another error: method intersect of object _global failed.